# Clipping and zooming platformer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently in the process of developing my first platformer, and I've decided that I want to bake my own acceleration and deceleration for movement instead of using unity's wonky physics.

This has brought up two roadblocks, one being that my character will just clip through objects like walls to jump over or off of, and the other is that if I try to switch directions while decelerating, my character will turn around, but it won't change directions and my acceleration will bypass the limit I set for it (in layman's, it zooms backwards).

I need help fixing this and can describe any of the functions of the variables if asked. There is no physics material on my character, and I am using physics for the jump.

All of the variables are defined in the unity editor for easier tweaking except for currentSpeed, jumpCount, FallTime and canJump, which I have serialized so I can observe them during testing.

I've tried changing

newPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x + currentSpeed, transform.position.y);
transform.position = newPos;

to addForce but it messed with the jumping.

```
public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour {
//walk Vars
[SerializeField] float currentSpeed;
[SerializeField] float maxSpeed;
[SerializeField] float jumpstart;
[SerializeField] float acceleration;
[SerializeField] float deceleraton;
int isFlip = 1;
Vector2 newPos;
Quaternion flip;

//jump Vars 
[SerializeField] public int jumpCount;
[SerializeField] public int jumpCountMax;
[SerializeField] public float jumpVel;
[SerializeField] public float fallMulti;
[SerializeField] public float shortMulti;
[SerializeField] public float fallTime;
[SerializeField] public float coyoteTime;
[SerializeField] bool canJump = true;
[SerializeField] bool didJump;

//references
Rigidbody2D rb;

private void Awake() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

//walk Functions
private void speedCalc() {
    currentSpeed += jumpstart * isFlip;
    if (currentSpeed * isFlip >= maxSpeed) {
        currentSpeed = maxSpeed * isFlip;
    }
    else {
        currentSpeed = (currentSpeed * acceleration);
    }
}

private void Start() {
    currentSpeed = 0;
}

private void Update() {
    //calculate coyote time
    if (fallTime == coyoteTime) {
        if (didJump == false) {
            jumpCount += 1;
        }
    }
    if (jumpCount >= jumpCountMax) {
        canJump = false;
    } else {
        canJump = true;
    }
    if (rb.velocity.y == 0) {
        jumpCount = 0;
        didJump = false;
    }

    //calculate isFlip
    if (Input.GetButton("Right")) {
        flip = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        transform.rotation = flip;
        isFlip = 1;
    } else if (Input.GetButton("Left")) {
        flip = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
        transform.rotation = flip;
        isFlip = -1;
    }

    //calculate acceleration & deceleration
    if (!Input.GetButton("Right") && !Input.GetButton("Left")) {
        if (currentSpeed * isFlip <= jumpstart) {
            currentSpeed = 0;
        } else {
            currentSpeed = (currentSpeed / deceleraton);
        }
    } else {
        speedCalc();
    }

    //implement falling and dyanamic jumping
    if (rb.velocity.y < 0) {
        fallTime += 1;
        rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity * (fallMulti - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    } else if (rb.velocity.y == 0) {
        fallTime = 0;
    }  else if (rb.velocity.y > 0 && !Input.GetButton("Jump")) {
        rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity * (shortMulti - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    //execute jump
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && canJump == true) {
        didJump = true;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpVel;
        jumpCount += 1;
    }

    //move character position
    newPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x + currentSpeed, transform.position.y);
    transform.position = newPos;
}
```

}

There where no error messages or anything but I'm 80% sure its my logic and ordering. The acceleration might be overlapping with the deceleration and the isFlip.

Comment: why are you resetting your jump stuff whenever `(rb.velocity.y == 0)`? Wouldn't  this sometimes reset your jump count at the peak of jumps?

Comment: Also, just use `currentSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(currentSpeed, -maxSpeed, maxSpeed);` to clamp the absolute value of your speed.

Comment: Ruzihm it's so that when the player lands he can jump again. with this i can tweak the number of jumps I can do and when I can do them in the editor and it keeps track of them. If I have a triple jump, each time I jump the counter will move up and when I get to three, I cant jump anymore. When I hit the ground it resets.

Comment: I thought it would but it works somehow. I think it is because the movement never reaches zero in a frame it just gets really close.

Comment: careful about `never`. a better alternative would be making the reset happen inside of `OnCollisionEnter` after checking if the collision is a floor below your character's feet.